# Quicksight parse date into month

Tags: amazon-quicksight

Maybe I missed it but I'm attempting to create a dynamic 'Month' parameter based on a datetime field - but can't seem to get just the month! ? Am I missing something ?

here's my source DTTM date/time field -
[image]

Answer (score 2):

In *Manage Data > Edit [selected] Data Set > Data source*

Just add '[calculated field](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/adding-a-calculated-field-analysis.html)':

```
truncDate('MM', date)
```

where MM returns the month portion of the date.

See [manual of truncDate function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/truncDate-function.html)

Comment: I tried this but oddly it doesn't just give month - it gives month and defaults to the 1st day of each month.

Comment: @Tony If you need just the month name itself, try `formatDate({your_timestamp_field}, 'MMMM')` or `MMM` for the Jan/Feb format

Comment: both return - sourceErrorCode:  
UNRECOGNIZED_FORMAT
sourceType:  
SPICE

Comment: @Tony I checked all above, it works perfectly. According to your error it seems your field has not timestamp format. Could you give the string representation of it?
See [Supported Date Formats](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/data-source-limits.html#supported-date-formats) and [Using Unsupported or Custom Dates](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/using-unsupported-dates.html) on QuickSight help

Comment: odd - just realized it works when your editing the data source fields but not within the viz>calculated fields

Answer (score 0):

The only place in Quicksight that you can get just a month, e.g. "September" is on a date-based axis of a visual. To do so, click the dropdown arrow next to the field name in the fields list, select "Format: (date)" then "More Formatting Options..." then "Custom" and enter MMMM in the Custom format input box. 
[Quicksight menu selection as described](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cxyaf.png)

This will then show the full month name on the date axis in your visual. NB It will use the full month name on this visual for ALL time period "Aggregations" - e.g. if you change the visual to aggregate by Quarter, it will display the full name of the quarter's first month etc.

If you are talking about "Parameters" in the Quicksight analysis view then you can only create a "Datetime" formatted parameter and then only use the "Date picker" box format for this parameter in a control (+ filter).

If you use a calculated field in either data preparation or analysis view the only date functions do not allow full month names as an output, you can get the month number as an integer or one of the allowed date formats here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/data-source-limits.html#supported-date-formats

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to hardcode the desired results using ifelse, min, and extract. 
Extract will pull out the month as an integer. Quicksight has a desire to beginning summing integers, so we'll put MIN in place to prevent that.

ifelse(min(extract('MM',Date)) = 1,'January',min(extract('MM',Date)) = 2,'February',min(extract('MM',Date)) = 3,'March',min(extract('MM',Date)) = 4,'April',min(extract('MM',Date)) = 5,'May',min(extract('MM',Date)) = 6,'June',min(extract('MM',Date)) = 7,'July',min(extract('MM',Date)) = 8,'August',min(extract('MM',Date)) = 9,'September',min(extract('MM',Date)) = 10,'October',min(extract('MM',Date)) = 11,'November',min(extract('MM',Date)) = 12,'December','Error')

Also, I apologize if this misses the mark. I'm not able to see the screeshot you posted due to security controls here at the office.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [extract](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/extract-function.html) function. Works like this:

`event_timestamp Nov 9, 2021`

```
extract('MM', event_timestamp)
11
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a [calculated field](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/adding-a-calculated-field-analysis.html) using the [extract](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/extract-function.html) function:

> extract returns a specified portion of a date value. Requesting a time-related portion of a date that doesn't contain time information returns 0.

```
extract('MM', date_field)
```